# A countdown timer with flasing color near the end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a flashing effect for my timer when the time reaches below 10s. This is what my timer currently looks like:

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);          
        
      if (--timer < 10) {
            setInterval(flash,1000);
        }
        
    }, 1000);    
}
function flash(){
          $("#time").toggleClass("backgroundRed");
    }
jQuery(function ($) {
    var fiveMinutes = 20,
        display = $('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
});
```

```css
  .backgroundRed{
        background: red;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div>Registration closes in <span id="time">00:20</span> minutes!</div>
</body>
```

Currently the flashes behave quite bizzare....
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're creating a new flash interval every second. Only create this once.

Comment: Can you please show me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a very simple alternative:

```js
let flashInterval;

function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);          
        
     if (--timer < 10 && !flashInterval) {
            flashInterval = setInterval(flash,1000);
        }
        
    }, 1000);    
}

function flash(){
    $("#time").toggleClass("backgroundRed");
}
```

By modifying your conditional to check whether an interval has already been set before setting a new flash interval, you can ensure this is set only once.